# How to run all output through gem before returning the html/json/etc to browser in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As stated, how do I take everything ever rendered from a controller action in Rails through a method in a gem so I can parse the output for specific text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
response.body
```

According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html#method-i-body this returns the content of the response as a string. This contains the contents of any calls to render.

Comment: Do you know if a gem could listen for this automatically or will I have to specifically call it from the controller?

Comment: You could potentially add an after_action event handler to the application_controller.rb so that you could run the code for every action that is called.